# Google places no longer showing predictions on the listView

Tags: flutter, google-api

My google predictions no longer shows predictions. I've been use this for the past 2-3 months now and it worked perfectly. But all of a sudden it stopped working. I've been stack for four days now. What should I do.

```
final fromController = TextEditingController();
var from = '';
DetailsResult? startPosition;
DetailsResult? endPosition;
late FocusNode startFocusNode;
late FocusNode endFocusNode;
late GooglePlace googlePlace;
List<AutocompletePrediction> predictions = [];
Timer? _debounce;
@override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    String apiKey = 'XXXXXXXX';
    googlePlace = GooglePlace(apiKey);
    startFocusNode = FocusNode();
    endFocusNode = FocusNode();
  }

@override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    startFocusNode.dispose();
    endFocusNode.dispose();
  }

void autoCompleteSearch(String value) async {
    var result = await googlePlace.autocomplete.get(value);
    if (result != null && result.predictions != null && mounted) {
      setState(() {
        predictions = result.predictions!;
      });
    }
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
.....
TextField(controller: fromController,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
          focusNode: startFocusNode,
          onChanged: (value) {
            if (_debounce?.isActive ?? false) {
              _debounce!.cancel();
            }
            _debounce = Timer(const Duration(microseconds: 1000), () {
              if (value.isNotEmpty) {
                autoCompleteSearch(value);
                setState(() {
                  from = value;
                });
              } else { 
                setState(() {
                  predictions = [];
                  startPosition = null;
                });
              }
            });
          },)

......
//This this the list view where it should show the list of predictions
//I didn't add the second TextField with the endFocusNode because it's basically the same thing as the startFocusNode
ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: predictions.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return ListTile(
                leading: const Icon(
                  Icons.pin_drop,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
                title: Text(
                  predictions[index].description.toString(),
                  style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                ),
                onTap: () async {
                  final placeId = predictions[index].placeId!;
                  final details = await googlePlace.details.get(placeId);
                  if (details != null && details.result != null && mounted) {
                    if (startFocusNode.hasFocus) {
                      setState(() {
                        startPosition = details.result;
                        fromController.text = details.result!.name!;
                        predictions = [];
                      });
                    } else {
                      setState(() {
                        endPosition = details.result;
                        toController.text = details.result!.name!;
                        predictions = [];
                      });
                    }
                  }
                },
              );
            },
          )),
}
```

To my AndroidManifest I added this

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="XXXXXXXXX" />
```

My ios AppDelegate

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import GoogleMaps

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GMSServices.provideAPIKey("XXXXXXXX")
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

Can some please help me. I don't know why this is happening all of a sudden